# How do I profile with IE F12 using console.profile()

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005(v=vs.85).aspx) I can set when profiling starts/stops using the calls consile.profile() and console.profileEnd().

However, running under F12 where I have the profiler page open but do not click the |> button - nothing is profiled. If I click that button I get a profile of everything from when the page starts and not just the part I want profiled.

How can I get just the part I want profiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution (no idea if this is the best solution). In your code put:

```
console.profileEnd();
console.profile("my profiling");
// code to profile
console.profileEnd();
```

Then open up F12, go to the profile page, and click F5 (the |> button). It'll run and after it hits the 2nd profileEnd you'll have 2 reports. Select the "my profiling" one.

Answer (score 1):

The console profiling APIs `console.profile` and `consoleprofileEnd` only function when IE11 is not in debug mode. Unfortunately launching F12 puts IE into debug mode. To get out of debug mode you need to start a profiler (any of them) and then the APIs will work. The memory tool is probably the easiest to start. Though starting then ending the script profiler works fine too :).

Comment: Wow.. that's a really nice gotcha right there.. Good job ms for not putting any console.warn in there for us when calling console.profile() in debug mode. Super intuitive.. /end rant